# Ruby on Rails: Deleting a post with Ajax in navigation and showing the following

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Thanks for reading!

So I'm relatively new to RoR (Rails 5) and I try to render posts of a user in a partial (`_posts_panel.html.erb`) which contains another partial: the navigation (`_posts_navigation.html.erb`). I'm using ajax to show the posts when clicked on in the navigation which is working fine.

Now I want to use it for deleting a post. The post is destroyed when I click on the button and I managed to remove it in navigation.

What is not working:

- the next post should be shown in the panel after the deletion
- when there is no post left I want to reload the panel because another partial (`_posts_empty.html.erb`) should be rendered

My Code:

`_posts_panel.html.erb:` (it is rendered in `show.html.erb` of user)

```
<% if @user.simple_posts.empty? %>
  <%= render 'simple_posts/shared/posts_empty' %>
<% else %>

  <div id="post-navigation">
    <%= render 'simple_posts/shared/posts_navigation' %>
  </div>

  <%= simple_posts_edit_button(current_user, @simple_post)%>
  <%= simple_posts_delete_button(current_user, @simple_post)%>   #button helper

  <div id="show_post">
    <%= render @simple_post %>
    <%= yield %>
   </div>

  <%end %>
```

`_posts_navigation.html.erb`

```
<div class="bootstrap-vertical-nav">
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <% @user.simple_posts.reverse_each do |post|%>
      <li class="nav-item" id="<%= @simple_post.id %>">
        <%= link_to post.title, user_simple_post_path(@user, post), remote: true, class:"nav-link text-dark" %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>

<% if @user.id == current_user.id %>
  <%= link_to "+ New Post", new_user_simple_post_path(current_user), class: "btn btn-info w-100", role: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

`destroy.js.erb`

```
$('li#<%= @simple_post.id %>').remove();
```

`simple_posts_controller.rb`

```
def destroy
    @simple_post.destroy
    @simple_post =current_user.simple_posts.first
    respond_to do |format|
    #   format.html { redirect_to simple_posts_url, notice: 'Simple post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I tried to append in `destroy.js.erb` the same code from showing the post `$('#show_post').html("<%=  escape_javascript render @simple_post %>");` but it's not working correctly. When deleting the first post (but only that one) the next one is shown but the post is not removed from the navigation. I also tried `$('#post-navigation').html("<%=  escape_javascript render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_navigation' %>");` and it nothing happens.

Also I tried to reload the whole panel with `$('#post-panel').html("<%=  escape_javascript render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_panel' %>");`in `show.html.erb` of user but again: nothing. I'm not sure if I have to specify in which view or partial exactly it has to render the partial.

I don't really know how to approach this further.

**Edit 1**

```
ButtonHelper.rb
def simple_posts_delete_button(current_user, simple_post)
    if(current_user.id == @user.id)
      link_to svg('x-square'), [current_user, simple_post], remote: true, method: :delete, class:"btn"
    end
  end
```

**Edit 2**

show-action from `simple_posts_controller.rb`

```
  def show
    @user = User.find{params[:id]}
    @simple_post = SimplePost.find(params[:id])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html # show.html.erb
    end
  end
```

`show.js.erb`

```
$('#post-actions').html("<%=  j render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_actions', locals: {simple_post: @simple_post, user: @user} %>");
$('#show-post').html("<%= j render @simple_post %>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your partials:

- First, to remove the post from your navigation you just need to update the partial, the post is already destroyed/removed at this point.
- After destroy, `@simple_post` in your button helper is not updated with ajax and still comes from the `users_controller` (where you set it the first time i presume)

You can put your action buttons inside a new partial and specify the locals.
You can also wrap the html inside a main div for the last update (when all the posts are deleted)

**_posts_panel.html.erb:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <% if @user.simple_posts.empty? %>
    <%= render 'simple_posts/shared/posts_empty' %>

  <% else %>
    <div id="post-navigation">
      <%= render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_navigation', locals: { simple_post: @simple_post } %>
    </div>

    <div id="post-actions"> #<-- new partial
      <%= render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_actions', locals: { simple_post: @simple_post } %>
    </div>

    <div id="show_post">
      <%= render @simple_post %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

**_posts_actions.html.erb:**

```
<%= simple_posts_edit_button(current_user, simple_post)%>
<%= simple_posts_delete_button(current_user, simple_post)%>
```

Note that you are not using the instance variable `@simple_post` anymore but the local one.

---

Now you can write your js like this:

**destroy.js.erb:**

```js
<% if @simple_post %> //<-- check if "@simple_post = current_user.posts.first" still exists after destroy
  $('#post-navigation').html("<%= j render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_navigation', locals: { simple_post: @simple_post } %>");
  $('#post-actions').html("<%= j render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_actions', locals: { simple_post: @simple_post } %>");
  $('#show_post').html("<%= j render @simple_post %>");

<% else %>
  $('#panel').html("<%= j render partial: 'simple_posts/shared/posts_empty' %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: After destroy, `@simple_form` in your button helper is not updated with ajax and still comes from the users_controller (where you set it the first time i presume)

Do you mean `@simple_post` ? Why is it not updated with ajax? I tried to implement your solution, but no partial actually gets updated. May the problem be my ButtonHelper?

Comment: @treefoc yes it's `@simple_post`, sorry for the typo, i edit my answer :)

Comment: So I managed every partial to work seperately: I needed to define `@user` in both the destroy and show method and also pass `user: @user` to the partials. In order to delete the correct post I have to rerender `_posts_actions.html.erb`in `show.js.erb` but the problem is: if I want to render both `@simple_post`and posts_actions it's not working. Where the simple_post should be rendered it stays empty

Comment: I don't really see how `@simple_post` and `posts_actions` partial shouldn't be rendered at the same time. In which controller `show.js.erb`hits ? Can you post it ?

Comment: Also after deleting a post the new `@simple_post` is not rendered

Comment: I solved it: I basically had "nested ids" which messed with everything. Thanks for your help!